# How to call one object file from another using c

Tags: c

I've been writing some simple console application in c and on linux and came across a problem. I need to run one object file from another.

When i want to open a text or binary file i would do something like this:

```
FILE* fp = fopen(path, mode);
```

and then just write to that file or read from it. But when it comes to object files i don't even know what to start with.

Globally, the situation is that there is a compiled object file which functionality needs to be tested (lets call it "target"). The test is driven by another compiled object file (let's call it "tester"). So, when i run the "tester" it queries for path to "target". When path is acquired, "tester" tests "target".

So, what i ask here is what this whole situation (coding of object files interaction) is called so i could go and rtfm? I lurked a bit and found some concepts like unit testing and APIs but brief view didn't give me strong impression that those things are what i'm looking for.

Thank you!

Comment: Dynamic linking, `dlopen`, etc?

Comment: @melpomene : I think it is more a question of basic multi-file linking: `cc -o program tester.o target.o`.

Comment: Or maybe one program running another (`system`, `popen`)?

Comment: Maybe you can read man page for `fork(2)` and `execve(2)`.

Comment: @liliscent: I think this won't help here.